# what can cause a time gap in data on an amazon ebs partition?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

we're admitedly new to the ebs world. having set up a new production couchdb server on amazon ec2+ebs, we ran into an issue where about 7 hours worth of data simply disappeared. to the point where the couchdb logs have a gap in them for that very time frame. we know that things were working fine, then we started to experience issues and realized that our database had been *reset* to an empty state.

thoughts? opnions? conjectures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that couchdb was starting up as a service, before the ebs was properly mounted. this caused the confusing behavoir.